# How can I wrap Objective-C code for visionOS only?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, visionos

I have the following code in Objective-C:

```objectivec
if (@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *)) {
    indicator.indicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge;
} else {
    indicator.indicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
}
```

But this is producing an error.

```
'UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge' is unavailable: not available on xrOS
```

I think I need that first conditional to get run so it doesn't even try to access `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge`.

But when I change the line to `if (@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, visionOS 1.0, *))`. I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized platform name visionOS
```

I also tried changing it to `xrOS 1.0` (since I heard that some internal usages had it as xrOS for a while. And while I don't get the second compiler error, it does still say it's unavailable.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TARGET_OS_VISION` to distinguish RealityKit only targets:

```
#if TARGET_OS_VISION

#else

#endif // TARGET_OS_VISION
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Objective-C is terrible when it comes to `@available`. If you were to write that same logic in Swift you would not get the deprecation warning. I don't know why Objective-C doesn't work better in this regard.

As you've seen, adding `xrOS 1.0` to the `@available` doesn't eliminate the deprecation warning despite the fact that at runtime, the `else` will not be executed due to the `@available`. So while it works at runtime, the compiler needlessly complains about a situation that it should not.

In my own experience, the only solution is to make use of compiler directives. While my experience is with Mac Catalyst and not visionOS, the issue is the same.

You need to write ugly code similar to the following:

```objectivec
#if TARGET_OS_VISION
    indicator.indicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge;
#else
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *)) {
        indicator.indicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge;
    } else {
        indicator.indicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    }
#endif
```

The bad part of this is the code duplication. Your only other options are converting to Swift or accepting the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TARGET_OS_VISION`

```
#if TARGET_OS_VISION

#else

#endif
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.